# What is the quickest way to remove one array of items from another?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have two arrays of strings:

```
 string[] all = new string[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"}

 string[] taken = new string[]{"a", "b"}
```

I want to generate a new string array with `c` and `d` which is `all - taken`.

Any quick way in `.net 3.5` to do this without a manual loop and creating new lists?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
var remains = all.Except(taken);
```

Note that this does *not* return an array.  But you need to ask yourself if you really need an array or if IEnumerable is more appropriate (hint: it almost always is).  If you really need an array, you can just call `.ToArray()` to get it.

In this case, there may be a big performance advantage to *not* using an array right away.  Consider you have "a" through "d" in your "all" collection, and "a" and "b" in your "taken" collection.  At this point, the "remains" variable doesn't contain *any* data yet.  Instead, it's an object that *knows how to tell you* what data will be there when you ask it.  If you never actually need that variable, you never did any work to calculate what items belong in it.

Answer (score 6):

You are using LINQ `Except` for it, like `all.Except(taken)`.

Answer (score 6):

```
string[] result = all.Except<string>(taken).ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: You don't have to state the type for the generic methods, the compiler is able to infer them.

Comment: I am aware of that. :-) But I think that it's useful to write the full syntax when you teach others.