# Remove items from one list that exist on another list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entity:

```
public class Media {
  public Int32 SourceId { get; set; }
  public String Key { get; set; } 
}
```

And I have dbContext.Medias and a list of Medias:

```
List<Media> medias = apiService.GetMedias(10);
```

I need the remove all items in medias which alreay exist in dbContext.Medias where two items are equal when SourceId && Key are equal. So I have:

```
medias = medias.Where(x => !dbContext.Medias.Any(y => y.Key == x.Id && y.SourceId == source.Id)).ToList();
```

The problem with this is that I am querying the database multiple times.

I would like to "invert" the solution which would become something like:

```
dbContext.Medias ...
```

Any idea of how can I do this?

Comment: It's probably not optimal performance wise, but wouldn't it help if you loaded dbContext into a var. And after that perform your query on the var.

Comment: That is what I need to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] all = new string[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
string[] taken = new string[]{"a", "b"}
var remains = all.Except(taken);
```

In your case, you can use this:

```
List<Media> result = all.Except<Media>(taken).ToList<Media>();
```

Reference: 
[What is the quickest way to remove one array of items from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884709/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-remove-one-array-of-items-from-another)

Comment: How would you use dbContextMedias in there?

Answer (score 0):

May be something like (Not sure if everything is right)

```
var mediasFromDB = dbContext.Medias.Where(x=>medias.Any(y => x.Key == y.Id && x.SourceId == source.Id);

medias = medias.Where(x => !mediasFromDB.Any(y => y.Key == x.Id && y.SourceId == source.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use .Except()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> media = new List<String> { "a", "b", "c" };
List<String> dbContext = new List<String> { "c", "d", "e" };

var resultset = dbContext.SelectMany(x => media.Where(y => y == x)).ToList(); //Distinct possible here if theres duplicate data ..
media = media.Where(e => resultset.All(r2 => e != r2)).ToList();

var res = media; // "a" , "b"
var resl = resultset; // "c"
```