# VB.Net - Remove lines containing

Tags: vb.net

If TextBox1 is:

```
football
tennis
basketball
```

And TextBox2.Text is:

```
volleyball
basketball
```

I want to remove every line from TextBox1.Text that contains a line from TextBox2.Text, so after that TextBox1 will be:

```
football
tennis
```

(basketball is removed because textbox2 contains it)

Comment: Split to an array then call .Except() => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884709/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-remove-one-array-of-items-from-another

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
' Convert newline-separated TextBox contents to string arrays
Dim all = TextBox1.Text.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim toRemove = TextBox2.Text.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)

Dim filtered = all.Except(toRemove)

' Fill the text box with the result (newline-separated)
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, filtered)
```

<sub>(All my VB code examples assume Option Strict On and Option Infer On.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim filter As String() = fleska.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(vbCrLf)})
For Each line As String In filter
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(line, "").Trim()
Next
```

This will remove all lines from TextBox2 that are in TextBox1.